# Почему yup не правильно пишет текст об ошибке?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Почему мне yup пишет не правильный текст об ошибке? С полем **"Имя"** все окей, но в поле **"Вес"** мне yup пишет **"Не больше двух чисел."**, а должно быть как сверху **"Поле должно быть заполнено."** В чем может быть проблемой и как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
firstName: yup
  .string()
  .matches(/^([^0-9]*)$/gm, "Только буквы.")
  .required("Поле должно быть заполнено."),
weight: yup
  .string()
  .matches(/^(\d{1,2})$/gm, "Не больше двух чисел.")
  .required("Поле должно быть заполнено."),
});

const { formState: { errors }, reset } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
```

Comment: Попробуй `required` и `matches` поменять местами. `\d{1,2}` значит от 1 до 2 цифр, то есть 1 цифра минимум, срабатывает раньше

Comment: На удивление, но помогло. Спасибо!